# MVC5 routing Programming C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

```
public static CustomerInfo Customer
{
    get
    {
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["CustomerData"] == null)
        {                    
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login");
            return new CustomerInfo();
        }
        else
        {
            return (CustomerInfo)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["CustomerData"];
        }
    }
    set
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["CustomerData"] = value;
    }
}
```

Whenever `HttpContext.Current.Session["CustomerData"]` is `null`, instead of redirecting to Login view in Account controller it is giving exception.

Comment: A property getter with side-effects is a bad idea.

Comment: Use an [action filter](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1095295/Check-Session-Timeout-by-Using-ActionFilters-in-MV) to check session and redirect.

Comment: Thanks Steve for suggestion to use action filter, but is it possible to redirect to login view from getter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
```

to redirect to another controller and method

Comment: You cannot do that here. That is what i thought of first as well but he's trying to do this in the getter of his static class - which returns CustomerInfo()

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["CustomerData"] == null)
    {                    
        Session["CustomerLogin"] = "True";
        return new CustomerInfo();
    }
    else
    {
        Session["CustomerLogin"] = "False";
        return (CustomerInfo)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["CustomerData"];
    }
```

Then in your controller check:

```
if(Convert.ToString(Session["CustomerLogin"]) == "True"){
   return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
}
```

Comment: Can't do that in his implementation - He's trying to do this in the getter of his static class - which returns `CustomerInfo`

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. Well then he needs to check what CustomerInfo returns and redirect accordingly.

Comment: Hi Laiman thanks for reply. but this public static method is inside public class CustomerInformation and it gives exception that RedirectToAction do not exist in current context

Comment: Yes. Do not try to redirect from the static method, instead return something you can check for when you call the method and do the redirecting there. see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Laiman for your reply. I am a new bee can you provide a small snippet on how to achive it. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: @Madhurima am not an expert either :-). What does CustomerInfo() return?

Comment: CustomerInfo is a class having properties like CustomerId, Name, Address and few more. Please provide the code for the solution you are suggesting to implement. Thanks

Comment: @Madhurima I have provided some code that can help you hopefully.

Comment: Thanks Laiman for you help to give me a direction on how to move further. certaininly if I create a Session["CustomerLogin"] = "True";
then I have to reset it also. your solution is good. Thanks

Comment: @Madhurima. Yes you would have to reset it indeed. If this helped resolved your issue then please mark it as the answer. An up vote would also be appreciated. Thanks.